# Multi List field validation fails and unable to update field value from Experience Editor

Tags: validation

**Updated**:

I have added field validations to multi list field to select items from the data source, validation works fine in the content editor. But In Experience editor, validation error message keeps popping-up and unable to update field value.

To replicate issue, please find below steps: 
1. Create Template with Multi List field (having data source items to select) 
2. Add Validation to Multi List field : I have used custom regular expression (^({[^}]+}[|]{[^}]+}[|]?){1,3}$) with validation text [Similar to this](https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/6796/sitecore-validation-rule-at-field-level-in-multi-list-value-selection-range)

[image]

Open experience editor to render field components accordingly:

3. Try to add/remove multi list items and update save.
4. Error message is popping-up all the time though and unable to update field value from experience editor

[image]

I'm using Sitecore 8.2 u3 | Validations are not working properly, error messages are shown though and unable to update field value to make it valid in Experience editor. I have tried in multiple browsers, facing the same issue.

Please let me know if anybody got expertise on these issues, add comments if need any further info.

Comment: what version of Sitecore do you have?

Comment: @SitecoreClimber: I'm using 8.2u3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sitecore has reported this issue as BUG and provided workaround fix as below.

**Fix:** 

comment out the following processor in your 'App_Config\sitecore.config' file:

"processor mode="on" type="Sitecore.Shell.Applications.ContentManager.ReturnFieldEditorValues.RegexValidate"

The Sitecore.Shell.Applications.ContentManager.ReturnFieldEditorValues.RegexValidate processor is a part of the uiReturnFieldEditorValues pipeline. 
The RegexValidate processor must check fields with a regular expression validation when you click the Ok button in your Edit Form. If the result is invalid, a pop-up with the validation message will appear.

So in this case multi-list field will not be validated when you will edit multi-list field in Experience Editor and click OK button. But will be validated when you will click on Save button, and an error message will appear if any field does not meet the regular expression.

For future reference, Please reach out to Sitecore with #49573.

Comment: Hi Sankar, Is there anyway we just apllied this config for multi list field?